# Dúvida com group by - sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu tenho essas tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE empresa (
    id_empresa     INT,
    nome_empresa   VARCHAR(40),
    razao_social   VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY ( id_empresa )
);

CREATE TABLE departamento (
    id_departamento     INT,
    id_empresa          INT,
    nome_departamento   VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY ( id_departamento ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( id_empresa )
        REFERENCES empresa ( id_empresa )
);

CREATE TABLE produto (
    id_produto        INT,
    id_departamento   INT,
    descricao         VARCHAR(40),
    valor             INT,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id_produto ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( id_departamento )
        REFERENCES departamento ( id_departamento )
);
```

E esses registros:

```
insert into empresa(id_empresa, nome_empresa, razao_social)
  values (1, 'Casas Bahia', 'Loja de produtos diversos');

insert into departamento(id_departamento, id_empresa, nome_departamento)
  values (1, 1, 'Eletrodomesticos');

insert into departamento(id_departamento, id_empresa, nome_departamento)
  values (2, 1, 'Produtos de Limpeza');

insert into produto(id_produto, id_departamento, descricao, valor)
  values (1, 1, 'Televisao', 1200);
insert into produto(id_produto, id_departamento, descricao, valor)
  values (2, 1, 'Computador', 4600);

insert into produto(id_produto, id_departamento, descricao, valor)
  values (3, 2, 'Detergente', 2);
insert into produto(id_produto, id_departamento, descricao, valor)
  values (4, 2, 'Esponja', 6);
```

Eu gostaria de retornar o nome do departamento, e o produto com o maior valor e o seu nome, mas ele sempre retorna valores a mais.

```
Eletrodomesticos    Computador  4600
Produtos de Limpeza Esponja     6


select d.nome_departamento, p.descricao, p.valor
    from departamento d, produto p
    inner join (
        select descricao, max(valor) as pmax
        from produto
        group by descricao
    ) gp on p.valor = gp.pmax
    where p.id_departamento = d.id_departamento;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Penso que esta *query* resolve o seu problema:

```
SELECT      d.nome_departamento
        ,   p2.descricao
        ,   p.valor
FROM        departamento    d
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      MAX(valor)      AS valor
                        ,   MAX(id_produto) AS id_produto
                        ,   id_departamento
                FROM        produto
                GROUP BY    id_departamento
            )               p   ON p.id_departamento    = d.id_departamento
INNER JOIN  produto         p2  ON p2.id_produto        = p.id_produto
```

Comment: Eu não entendi para que o Max nesse linha: MAX(id_produto) AS id_produto

Comment: Precisa dele para depois fazer o JOIN com a tabela PRODUTO. Se não tivesse esse MAX não seria possível agrupar apenas por departamento (ia obrigá-lo a colocar no GROUP BY e ia devolver dados errados) e não ia conseguir obter a informação do produto.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade acredito que poderá utilizar uma consulta como esta:

```
select distinct d.nome_departamento, p.descricao, p.valor
from departamento d, produto p
where p.id_departamento = d.id_departamento
  and p.id_produto in (
    select top 1 p1.id_produto
    from produto p1
    where p1.descricao = p.descricao
    order by p1.valor desc
);
```

Removendo o `inner join` e validando o produto por id (a subconsulta se encarrega de trazer o maior valor)

Comment: Não esta funcionando.

Comment: é, vi que tinha feito besteira :P veja se ajuda agora..